# Error in reading a ascii encoded csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, encoding, ascii

I have a csv file named Qid-NamedEntityMapping.csv having data like this:

```
Q1000070    b'Myron V. George'
Q1000296    b'Fred (footballer, born 1979)'
Q1000799    b'Herbert Greenfield'
Q1000841    b'Stephen A. Northway'
Q1001203    b'Buddy Greco'
Q100122     b'Kurt Kreuger'
Q1001240    b'Buddy Lester'
Q1001867    b'Fyodor Stravinsky'
```

The second column is 'ascii' encoded, and when I am reading the file using the following code, then also it not being read properly:

```
import chardet
import pandas as pd

def find_encoding(fname):
    r_file = open(fname, 'rb').read()
    result = chardet.detect(r_file)
    charenc = result['encoding']
    return charenc


my_encoding = find_encoding('datasets/KGfacts/Qid- 
NamedEntityMapping.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('datasets/KGfacts/Qid- 
NamedEntityMapping.csv',error_bad_lines=False, encoding=my_encoding)
```

But the output looks like this:
[image: output]

Also, I tried to use encoding='UTF-8'. but still, the output is the same.
What can be done to read it properly?

Comment: Please do not post links. Include the original data in the text form. We need to see the _real_ data to answer your question, not the screenshot. Looks like you have a tab-separated file (TSV); for starters, pass `sep='\t'` to the reader.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough points to post an image directly. I used sep='\t', but now also, the encoded part is still there.

Comment: Do not post an image, post the actual data as text. Something that can be copied and pasted.

Comment: I tried to copy the text but I converted into the image itself and put a link to it. I am able to paste the content in the comment, but it also comes in one line. I am posting the content in the next comment if you need.

Comment: But please put it into the question instead of the useless image.

Comment: Q1000070 b'Myron V. George'
Q1000296 b'Fred (footballer, born 1979)'
Q1000799 b'Herbert Greenfield'
Q1000841 b'Stephen A. Northway'
Q1001203 b'Buddy Greco'
Q100122 b'Kurt Kreuger'
Q1001240 b'Buddy Lester'
Q1001867 b'Fyodor Stravinsky'

Comment: The ideal solution is to fix the code that creates the file - it's converting encoded bytestrings (b'xxx') to `str` by doing `str(bytestring)` instead of `bytestring.decode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an improperly saved TSV file. Once you circumvent the TAB problem (as suggested in my comment), you can convert the column with names to a more suitable representation.

Let's assume that the second column of the dataframe is called "names". The `b'XXX'` thing is probably a bytes [mis]representation of a string. Convert it to a `bytes` object with `ast.literal_eval` and then decode to a string:

```
import ast
df["names"].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(bytes.decode)
#0    Myron...
#1    Fred...
```

Last but not least, your problem has almost nothing to do with encodings or charsets.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like the CSV is actually tab separated; so you need to have `sep='\t'` in the `read_csv` function. It's reading everything else as a single column, except "born 1979" in the first row, as that is the only cell with a comma in it.

Comment: I did what you told. It solved half of the problem. Encode part is still there is the second column.